# Do there exist manifolds which cannot be smoothly embedded in a compact manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Is it always possible to find a manifold $N$, compact, and a diffeomorphism of $M$ onto an open subset of $N$?

I know that if $M$ is given some Riemannian metric, then it may be "non-extendible." However, I don't understand any examples of this phenomenon, so I cannot judge the extent to which it cares about the metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in the category of topological spaces you have always [Alexandrov compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) (and other compactification schemes also), in the context of manifolds, it appears [that the answer is no](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34611/3948).

Comment: It seems to me that the linked answer might also provide an example of a non-extendible incomplete Riemannian manifold, if a metric is put on it so that a geodesic will reach "infinity" in finite time. (For example, by making the manifold of finite length, so that it appears to be like cone with infinitely many holes appearing in the direction of the cone point.)  If it were to embed isometrically as an open in another submanifold, then I think the cone point would have to be filled in, so the embedding would factor through a closed surface, which cannot happen. Does that make sense?

Comment: There are much easier examples for inextendible incomplete Riemannian manifolds. Take any non-trivial cone and remove the vertex for example. (Concrete example, the set $\{x^2 + y^2 = z^2, z > 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its induced metric.)

Comment: Got it, thanks. And an argument for non-extendibility is just that the curvature wouldn't extend continuously? This one could see by parallel transport in the original cone around the new point - I am pretty convinced that any non-trivial extension would have to add the cone point, but this feels a little fishy to me: if the extension was into a complete manifold, then the cone point would have to be added for metric reasons, but I am not convinced that the cone point must be there if the completeness of the extension is dropped... any insight into how to argue this?

Comment: What other point could you add? Any new point has to be at infinity or at the boundary of the tip to keep the manifold stricture. The former cannot be a Riemannian extension.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not always possible. Consider the "orientable surface of infinite genus": let $S$ be a torus with two small disks removed, and consider the colimit of
$$S \to S \# S \to S \# S \# S \to \dots$$
where the connected sum means that you glue along the disks that you have removed. (Imagine a surface with an infinite number of holes, basically.) Then you can check the classification of closed surfaces to see that this isn't homeomorphic to any open subset of any of them.